# How to manually change the column annotation color with ComplexHeatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

I have the following code that uses [ComplexHeatmap](https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap) ([doc](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/introduction.html#general-design)) package to make the heatmap:

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)

nof_elem <- 4

set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(nof_elem * nof_elem), nof_elem)
rownames(mat) <- paste0("R", 1:nof_elem)
colnames(mat) <- paste0("C", 1:nof_elem)
mat



column_ha <- HeatmapAnnotation(cluster = anno_block(
  gp = gpar(fill = 2:15),
  labels = c("group1", "group2", "group3"),
  labels_gp = gpar(col = "white", fontsize = 10),

  # Tried this but didn't work
  # col = list(cluster = c("group1" = "red", "group2" = "blue", "group3" = "black"))
))

Heatmap(mat,
  cluster_columns = FALSE,
  cluster_rows = FALSE,
  top_annotation = column_ha,
  column_split = c(1, 2, 2, 3),
  show_column_names = FALSE
)
```

It produces the following figure:

[image]

As shown in the figure above. There are actually two tasks I need to do:

1. How can I manually change the group block color? (group1 = red; group2 = blue, group3 = black)
2. How can I remove the number at the very top?